# insert into a table and get the error: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I've supplied all the values. Still it gives me error that I did not supply value for binding 1. This is My code:

```
 conn = sqlite3.connect('Minerva_app.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("""
                    INSERT INTO tbl_contracts(contractName, category_id, startDate, endDate, price, periods, dateCreated
                        , dateUpdated, notes, activeStatus, file_id) 
                     VALUES(:contractName1, :category1, :startDate1, :endDate1, :price1, :periods1, :dateCreated1
                     , :dateUpdated1, :notes1, :activeStatus1, :file_id1)
                """,
                  {
                      ':contractName1': self.contactNameEntry.get(),
                      ':category1': cat_id,
                      ':startDate1': self.startDateEntry.get(),
                      ':endDate1': self.endDateEntry.get(),
                      ':price1': self.priceEntry.get(),
                      ':periods1': self.periodsEntry.get(),
                      ':dateCreated1': now,
                      ':dateUpdated1': now,
                      ':notes1': self.notesText.get("1.0", tk.END),
                      ':activeStatus1': self.active.get(),
                      ':file_id1': file_id1
                  }
                  )
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

this is the error:

```
    ':file_id1': file_id1
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 1.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Remove the colons in the dictionary key strings.

Comment: Michael Butscher. Thank you very much!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63592114/1497139 for getting better debug info